# How to force updating a value which has been put to array as a text for an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to create a timer for questions which I get from database. User will need to answer them in 5 minutes. Timer structure is in the Timer class which I placed in the separate file.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Q</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>Timer</th>
    </tr>
    {this.state.unaccQst}
</table>
<form action="" onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    ...

    questionCollector(newForm).then( //get questions from database
        data => {
            let qstDetArr = []
            for(let qstDetails of data){

                ...

                var timer1 = new Timer(5,0)  //set a 5 minute timer for each of the questions
                var timer2 = setInterval(() => {  
                    let getTime = timer1.getTime()   //check the current time

                    if(getTime.minutes == 0 && getTime.seconds == 0) {
                        console.log("DELETED")
                        clearInterval(timer2)
                    }
                    else this.setState({[`time_${qstDetails["_id"]}`]: `${getTime.minutes}:${getTime.seconds}`})   //set the current time to a state
                    console.log(this.state[`time_${qstDetails["_id"]}`]) //this console.log works perfectly (like 4:57, 4:56, 4:55, etc...)
                }, 1000)

                qstDetArr.push(<tr> //push a table row to an array
                    <td>{qstDetails["_id"]}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.type}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.translations.en.Q}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.translations.en.A}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.translations.en.B}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.translations.en.C}</td>
                    <td>{qstDetails.translations.en.D}</td>
                    <td>{this.state[`time_${qstDetails["_id"]}`]}</td> //this line should update every time the state will update, but it doesn't
                </tr>)}
            this.setState({unaccQst: [...this.state.unaccQst, ...qstDetArr]})
        },
        (err) => {}
    )
}}>
```

Everything works fine besides the line:

```
<td>{this.state[`time_${qstDetails["_id"]}`]}</td>
```

which value stucked. It's the same as it was when I put it to an array.

There needs to be a way to update it, but it doesn't work even when i want to update it with more polite state (like just i++)

Comment: Why do you put React elements into the state?

Comment: Well, they can be got from the database multiple times (whenever user submits my form) and I want them to be displayed as appended to the table.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I managed to do it simply by putting into a state only the data I needed to construct tr with and do it later using map():

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Q</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>Timer</th>
    </tr>
    {this.state.unaccQst.map(qst => {
        return <tr>
            <td>{qst["_id"]}</td>
            <td>{qst.type}</td>
            <td>{qst.translations.en.Q}</td>
            <td>{qst.translations.en.A}</td>
            <td>{qst.translations.en.B}</td>
            <td>{qst.translations.en.C}</td>
            <td>{qst.translations.en.D}</td>
            <td>{this.state[`time_${qst["_id"]}`]}</td>
        </tr>
    })}
</table>
```